# Simple expression evaluation syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, expression, eval, evaluation

I'm working on a dashboard/gui with small widgets. For each widget, the end user should be able to specify on which conditions a widget is visible (*based on values from other objects*). For example, the widget for showing the state of motion sensors should be hidden when somebody is home. (*because it's only used to detect presence of unwanted visitors, not to track/follow residents when they are at home*).

A sample '*expression*' the user should be able to insert manually, could be `{value} = 0`, where `{value}` will be based on the state of the alarm system.

To allow more situations, we've already come up with expressions such as:
`{value} > 0`,  `{value} >= 0`,  `{value} != 0`, `{value} < 0`, `{value} <= 0`, but also more complex ones like , `{value & 2} = 2` (bitwise operations), `{value % 3} = 1` (modulo) or `{value} in 0-10` (for a range).

In order to prevent me from comming up with my own syntax, I've searched for any existing ones. I've already found [math.js](https://mathjs.org/), but that's not exactly what i'm looking for. Otherwise, I'm ending up in the [documentation of operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) for Javacript for example.

And of course, I can use regular expressions/eval myself in order to evaluate the user defined expression in order to check if there's a match, so the widget can be show/hidden. But when there already is something like that (and documented), why reinvent the wheel.

Despite all the manuals for programming languages, is there some general syntax for evaluating expressions?

Comment: if you have a backend I'd strongly recommend using something like V8 and validate it on a server side.

Comment: "*is there some general syntax for evaluating expressions*" - no. You can embed a whole programming language, an existing library, or write your own parser and interpreter.

Comment: "*I'm ending up in the documentation of operators for Javacript for example*" - not sure how you ended up there. You don't want to evaluate JavaScript, but only "simple expressions", right?

Comment: Yes, I want simple expressions. I want to be able to provide non-technical users the ability to do such things, so I was looking for a (good documented) syntax. Can't imagine no one hasn't done something similar before, so was looking for examples.